# JQuery | change a part of a string with links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="TopMenu">
<h3>Create an Account</h3>
<h3>yup</h3>
<h3>lol</h3>
<a href="#">yo</a>
<ul>
    <li sytle="display:">
        <a href="#">start</a> or
         <a href="#">finish</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

and I'm using:

```
    $('.TopMenu li:contains("or")').each(function() {
     var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('or', 'triple'));  
});
```

It works fine, but suddenly the links aren't active,
how do I fix it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.text()` to `.html()`

```
$('.TopMenu li:contains("or")').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(text.replace('or', 'triple'));  
});
```

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFs2G/)

Comment: `<a href="c-or-d.html">cake or death</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what your jQuery basically translates to when it's being run:

```
text = this.textContent;
// text = "\n\t\tstart or\n\t\t finish\n\t\t\n";
text = text.replace('or','triple');
// text = "\n\t\tstart triple\n\t\t finish\n\t\t\n";
this.textContent = text;
// essentially, remove everything from `this` and put a single text node there
```

Okay, that's not a great explanation XD The point is, setting `textContent` (or, in jQuery, calling `.text()`), replaces the element's contents with that text.

What you want to do is just affect the text nodes. I'm not aware of how to do this in jQuery, but here's some Vanilla JS:

```
function recurse(node) {
    var nodes = node.childNodes, l = nodes.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( nodes[i].nodeType == 1) recurse(node);
        else if( nodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
            nodes[i].nodeValue = nodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/\bor\b/g,'triple');
        }
    }
}
recurse(document.querySelector(".TopMenu"));
```

Note the regex-based replacement will prevent "boring" from becoming "btripleing". Use [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) and its magic powers or I shall buttbuttinate you!

Answer (score 0):

Since `or` is a text node, you can use **[.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)** along with **[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** instead:

```
$('.TopMenu li:contains("or")').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
    }).replaceWith(' triple ');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3RyYR/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit more complicated task. You need to replace text in text nodes (`nodeType === 3`), which can be done with `contents()` and `each` iteration:

```
$('.TopMenu li:contains("or")').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace('or', 'triple');
    }
});
```

All other approaches will either rewrite the markup in the `<li>` element (removing all attached events), or just remove the inner elements.

As discussed in the comments below, fool-proof solution will be to use replacement with regular expression, i.e. `this.nodeValue.replace(/\bor\b/g, 'triple')`, which will match all `or` as *standalone words* and not as parts of words.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/48E6M/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah, `\bor\b` will do the job in this case. However, if the OP has only `or` text there, no matter.

Comment: You can't rely on that though - OP could conceivably go "oh hey, this code works, let's use it... oh, StackOverflow, it doesn't work again"... in that case they might link to your answer that they tried and make you look silly :p I'm exaggerating though.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Persuaded `:P`

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/7WF9J/)***

You are placing the anchors into text by doing that. You should iterate the matched elements' childNodes and only use replace on their textContent to avoid modifying any html tags or attributes.

```
$('.TopMenu li:contains("or")').each(function() {
 for(var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++){
    if(this.childNodes[i].nodeName != "#text") continue;
    this.childNodes[i].textContent = this.childNodes[i].textContent.replace(' or ', ' triple ');
 }
});
```

Comment: `<a href="c-or-d.html">cake or death?</a>`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - It is definitely not ideal, but it works for the exact example :P I did upvote your answer as it fully solves the entire problem space.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - In the spirit of addressing a larger problem space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to us `.html()` instead of `.text()`,

Like this:

```
$('.TopMenu li:contains("or")').each(function() {
 var text = $(this).html();
$(this).html(text('or', 'triple'));  
});
```

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Mamj/

Comment: And what, pray tell, would you do if the HTML were `<a href="c-or-d.html">cake or death</a>`?

Comment: @VisioN I know. I'm going to post my Cake or Death comment on all of the ones where it's a problem XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Does this no longer work? I understand where you are coming from but it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/7Mamj/1/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The question was to make the "or" in between the links "triple". The question was not to change every single occurrence of "or" throughout the document?

Comment: If it were that simple, the answer would just be "change the source HTML". Your code doesn't work because `text('or','triple')` should probably be `text.replace('or','triple')`, and even then ask yourself what would happen if your code encountered a link like the one I posted in my first comment here.

Comment: I have added your link in the code. I am confused, is this not working correctly? jsfiddle.net/7Mamj/1

Comment: Well no, it's not, it's throwing an error that "text is not a function". [Even after correcting that](http://jsfiddle.net/7Mamj/2/), if you pay attention you'll notice that the "cake or death" link now points to `c-triple-d.html`, which is not the desired effect!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Sorry about that, I was viewing a cached version. But, just for arguments sake, for the exact use the OP wanted (without using the word "or" in links). Using Jquery, the library the OP wished to use, would accomplish the task just fine. In this specific use. Not saying your way is not the correct way for most uses :)